# How to display MathML equation and image in React Native app using MathJax?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mathjax, react-native-render-html

```
  <MathJax
    style={styles.test_ques}
    html={props?.info?.question?.question_text}
    mathJaxOptions={{
      showMathMenu: false,
      showProcessingMessages: false,
      messageStyle: 'none',
      SVG: {
        useGlobalCache: false,
      },
      extensions: [
        'mml2jax.js',
        'MathMenu.js',
        'MathZoom.js',
        'AssistiveMML.js',
        'a11y/accessibility-menu.js',
        'tex2jax.js',
      ],
      jax: ['input/MathML', 'input/TeX', 'output/CommonHTML', 'output/SVG'],
      tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [
          ['$', '$'],
          ['\\(', '\\)'],
        ],
        displayMath: [
          ['$$', '$$'],
          ['\\[', '\\]'],
        ],
        processEscapes: true,
      },
      TeX: {
        extensions: [
          'AMSmath.js',
          'AMSsymbols.js',
          'noErrors.js',
          'noUndefined.js',
          'autoload-all.js',
        ],
      },
    }}
    {...WebView}
  />
```

When I use Mathjax in React Native it gives me Paragraph, MathML, in the place image there is an empty box what can I do to fix this problem I also use react-native-render-html but it does not render MathML part